# C#: How to Delete the matching substring between 2 strings?

Tags: c#, string, string-matching

If I have two strings ..
say

> string1="Hello Dear c'Lint"

and

> string2="Dear"

.. I want to **Compare the strings** first and **delete** the matching substring .. 
*the result of the above string pairs is:*

> "Hello  c'Lint"

*(i.e, two spaces between* "Hello" *and* "c'Lint"*)*
 
for simplicity, we'll assume that string2 will be the sub-set of string1 .. (i mean string1 will contain string2)..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do this only:

```
string string1 = textBox1.Text;
string string2 = textBox2.Text;

string string1_part1=string1.Substring(0, string1.IndexOf(string2));
string string1_part2=string1.Substring(
    string1.IndexOf(string2)+string2.Length, string1.Length - (string1.IndexOf(string2)+string2.Length));

string1 = string1_part1 + string1_part2;
```

Hope it helps. It will remove only first occurance.

Answer (score 14):

What about

```
string result = string1.Replace(string2,"");
```

**EDIT**: I saw your updated question too late :)
An alternative solution to replace only the first occurrence using Regex.Replace, just for curiosity:

```
string s1 = "Hello dear Alice and dear Bob.";
string s2 = "dear";
bool first = true;
string s3 = Regex.Replace(s1, s2, (m) => {
    if (first) {
        first = false;
        return "";
    }
    return s2;
});
```

Comment: that would be
string1 = string1.Replace(string2,"");
:o)

Answer (score 5):

you would probably rather want to try

```
string1 = string1.Replace(string2 + " ","");
```

Otherwise you will end up with 2 spaces in the middle.

Comment: So you require the double space in the middle?

Comment: But Your answer is valuable too .. so +

Answer (score 4):

```
string1.Replace(string2, "");
```

Note that this will remove *all* occurences of `string2` within `string1`.

Comment: ohk .. fine .. Then how to avoid that .. I mean, suppose, if I want to delete only the first occurrence of string2 then?

Answer (score 2):

Off the top of my head, removing the first instance *could* be done like this

```
var sourceString = "1234412232323";
var removeThis = "23";

var a = sourceString.IndexOf(removeThis);
var b = string.Concat(sourceString.Substring(0, a), sourceString.Substring(a + removeThis.Length));
```

Please test before releasing :o)

Answer (score 0):

Try This One only one line code...

```
string str1 = tbline.Text;
string str2 = tbsubstr.Text;
if (tbline.Text == "" || tbsubstr.Text == "")
{
    MessageBox.Show("Please enter a line and also enter sunstring text in textboo");
}
else
{
    **string delresult = str1.Replace(str2, "");**
    tbresult.Text = delresult;
}**
```